# Append collection of elements to another collection in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-append

I'd like to [append outside loop](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/). I've got 2 collections. One of the elements that I want to append, and one of the elements that I want to append to. Namely, I have one collection of 3 divs and one collection of 3 paragraphs.

I want to append so that paragraph 1 will be appended to div 1, pragraph 2 to div 2 and paragraph 3 to div 3.

Is that possible without using a loop?

Right now I am doing it this way:

```
var divs = $('<div>'), paragraphs = $(), arr = [['class1','text1'],['class2','text2'],['class3','text3']];
for (i = 0; i < 3;i++)
{
    paragraphs = $('<p class="' + arr[i][0] + '">' + arr[i][1] + '</p>').appendTo(divs.eq(i));
}
```

Comment: if you already know your paragraphs you can add them at render time and just hide them

Comment: FYI, `paragraphs` is not being used and it's being re-written. Both, `<div>` and `<p>` are being dynamically generated? Or, are you trying to append to an existent `<div>` element?

Comment: @Alexander I am trying to add dynamic generated elements to existent collection of elements. anyway I edited my example because my previous one was wrong / confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**, due to changes in original example, improved answer
yes internally it will use a loop anyway, but i think what you are asking for is

```
divs = $('div'), paragraphs = $(), arr = [['class1','text1'],['class2','text2'],['class3','text3']];
divs.append(function(i, h){
    paragraphs = $('<p class="' + arr[i][0] + '">' + arr[i][1] + '</p>').appendTo(divs.eq(i));
    return paragraphs;
});
```

Hope this helps

Note: in the question you wrote

```
divs = $('<div>');
```

and it should be

```
divs = $('div');
```

Comment: I just gave an example, it probably not a good why and this is the reason u gave me that answer. - **Edited my example so it wont confuse**